# Jquery validation plugin dynamically add rules if control exists

Tags: jquery-validate

I am adding a whole bunch of Jquery validation rules dynamically. I am getting error because some of the textboxes are hidden based on user selection on the page before and therefore do not exist on the page. How do I check if the textbox exists before adding the validation rules?

Here are the validation rules being added:

```
 $('[id$="txtLastName"]').rules('add', {
    isSpecialChar: true,
    maxlength: 13,
    oneOrBothEntered: "txtFacility",
    messages: {
        oneOrBothEntered: "Either Provider Name or Facility Name must be entered"
    }
});
$('[id$="txtFirstName"]').rules('add', {
    isSpecialChar: true,
    maxlength: 11,
    conditionallyRequired: "txtLastName",
    messages: {
        conditionallyRequired: "This field is required."
    }
});
```

...and a whole bunch more. So say txtLastName was hidden, this code breaks. How do I check first if txtlastname exists before adding the rules?

EDIT:
Per @sparky's comment, adding HTML for fields:

```
 <div class="container1">
                    <span class="span150Padded">Last</span>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName" runat="server" CssClass="textBoxMedium"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
                <div class="container1">
                    <span class="span150Padded">First</span>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server" CssClass="textBoxMedium"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
```

The reason I am adding the rules dynamically is because I am using master pages so my fields are renamed. I couldn't use the <%=textbox.ClientID%> method because my validation is in a separate js file which is referenced and called from my aspx page, and a js file won't recongnize something like that. After alot of back and forth, I have found that the cleanest solution was to add the validation rules dynamically.

If you have another suggestion for me, please let me know.

Comment: Your code is incomplete... how do these new elements get added to the page in the first place?  How about just calling the `rules('add')` method immediately after you add the new element?

Comment: Added HTML of elements. They are not added dynamically. Added explanation of why I am adding rules dynamically if textboxes are there from the get-go. Let me know if I'm doing it all wrong...Thanks:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the jQuery Validate plugin or any of its methods, the plugin will not target all elements if your selector targets more than one element.

Use the [jQuery `.each()` method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) to target all elements.

```
$('[id$="txtLastName"]').each(function() {
    $(this).rules('add', {
        ...
    });
});
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to avoid using `.each()`, then target the *one* element.

```
$('#justOneField').rules('add', {
    ...
});
```

Comment: This is great - it works! Is there any other way of doing it like saying if exists... I am just a bit nervous about this because I will not be supporting this app, I am just writing it. So I am trying to make it as readable as possible and something like this is a bit confusing - why are we doing a .each method on a single textbox?? If this is the only known way, I will go with it and try to explain in comments...

Comment: @user2521483, jQuery is already doing an _"if exists"_ of sorts.  When a jQuery selector matches nothing, then nothing happens.

Comment: @user2521483, You're doing an `.each()` because your chosen jQuery selector, `$=`, is not targeting just a single element.  If you want to avoid using `.each()`, then just target the one particular element.  See edited answer.

Comment: Oh, I see. I am using that selector because the id changes at runtime because I am using Master pages. I added clientIdMode=Static and tried targeting one element using the id (like you have in your edit). It works fine if the element is on the page but if it is not, I get the original error. Is there a way to say if element exists, $('#justOneField').rules('add'...

Comment: @user2521483, I think you're missing the point...  _"if element exists"_ is what jQuery is already doing for you when you use _any_ jQuery selector.  Using _your_ more generic jQuery selector, you must use an `.each()`... it is the proper way to get this plugin to work in this context.

Comment: If it is doing an 'if element exists' for all selectors then why does it error when the element does not exist when i use the $('#justOneField') selector? I'm sorry that I'm not understanding it...thanks for taking the time to explain. I really appreciate it!

Comment: @user2521483, jQuery is not giving you the error.  The plugin is.  Because it's trying to apply the `rules()` method to an element that does not exist.

Comment: I really appreciate your explanations. As usual, you're head-on - its the plugin giving me the error. So now to rephrase my question (now that I am more knowledgable:) using the $('#justOneField') selector, is there any way to tell the plugin to only add the rules if the element exists (other than using .each() method)?

Comment: @user2521483, The `function` contained within the `each` only runs if/after a matched element is found... this is the way to do it.  Don't be afraid of `.each()`.  It's a very popular jQuery method.

Comment: Ok, Sparky, I'm going with it:) Thanks for all your help, very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Per the [documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/)

```
$("#myform").validate({
ignore: ":hidden"
});
```